# "hg commit/diff" crash on my Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, mercurial

I just run `hg commit -m "xxx"` on my Mac and then got the message:

`zsh: illegal hardware instruction hg commit`

and `hg diff` also be crash, but the `hg commit` is OK. When I save the commit message with vim, it's behavior same as `hg commit -m "xxx"`.

I guess the problem is about Python, but I don't know how to fix it. If you know, tell me please.
Here is the part of crash report from Mac:

```
Process:         Python [695] Path:           
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:      Python Version:         2.7.3 (2.7.3) Code Type:     
X86-64 (Native) Parent Process:  zsh [367] User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2013-03-07 09:55:14.307 +0800 OS Version:      Mac OS
X 10.8.2 (12C60) Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          317288 sec Crashes Since Last
Report:           5 Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   5 Anonymous
UUID:                      6B0FD4D3-FF2D-685D-7308-4285733D9C69

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL) Exception Codes:
0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0  
datetime.so                     0x0000000106ac2064
datetime_from_timestamp + 124 1   datetime.so                  
    0x0000000106ac5c70 datetime_utcfromtimestamp + 64 2  
org.python.python               0x0000000105e0239b PyEval_EvalFrameEx +
7873 3   org.python.python              0x0000000105e06743
fast_function + 182 4   org.python.python            
    0x0000000105e035a8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12494 5   org.python.python  
    0x0000000105e06743 fast_function + 182 6   org.python.python         
    0x0000000105e035a8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12494 7   org.python.python  
    0x0000000105e003b0 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1638 8   org.python.python    
    0x0000000105da8719 function_call + 336 9   org.python.python         
    0x0000000105d8b3a1 PyObject_Call + 101 10  org.python.python         
    0x0000000105d87c00 PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs + 190 11 
org.python.python               0x0000000105dbab37
_PyObject_GenericGetAttrWithDict + 429 12  org.python.python                0x0000000105e02172 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 7320 13  org.python.python   
    0x0000000105e06743 fast_function + 182 14  org.python.python         
    0x0000000105e035a8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12494 15  org.python.python  
    0x0000000105da0166 gen_send_ex + 240 16  org.python.python           
    0x0000000105e00ad1 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 1527 17  org.python.python   
    0x0000000105da0166 gen_send_ex + 240 18  org.python.python           
    0x0000000105e00ad1 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 1527 19  org.python.python   
    0x0000000105e003b0 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1638 20  org.python.python    
    0x0000000105e067a7 fast_function + 282 21  org.python.python         
    0x0000000105e035a8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12494 22  org.python.python  
    0x0000000105e003b0 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1638 23  org.python.python    
    0x0000000105da8719 function_call + 336 24  org.python.python         
    0x0000000105d8b3a1 PyObject_Call + 101 25  org.python.python         
    0x0000000105e040e1 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15367 26  org.python.python  
    0x0000000105e003b0 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1638 27  org.python.python    
    0x0000000105da8719 function_call + 336 28  org.python.python         
    0x0000000105d8b3a1 PyObject_Call + 101 29  org.python.python         
    0x0000000105e040e1 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15367 30  org.python.python  
    0x0000000105e003b0 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1638 31  org.python.python    
    0x0000000105e067a7 fast_function + 282 32  org.python.python         
    0x0000000105e035a8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12494 33  org.python.python  
    0x0000000105e003b0 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1638 34  org.python.python    
    0x0000000105e067a7 fast_function + 282 35  org.python.python         
    0x0000000105e035a8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12494 36  org.python.python  
    0x0000000105e003b0 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1638 37  org.python.python    
    0x0000000105e067a7 fast_function + 282 38  org.python.python         
    0x0000000105e035a8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12494 39  org.python.python  
    0x0000000105e06743 fast_function + 182 40  org.python.python         
    0x0000000105e035a8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12494 41  org.python.python  
    0x0000000105e003b0 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1638 42  org.python.python    
    0x0000000105e067a7 fast_function + 282 43  org.python.python         
    0x0000000105e035a8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12494 44  org.python.python  
    0x0000000105e06743 fast_function + 182 45  org.python.python         
    0x0000000105e035a8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12494 46  org.python.python  
    0x0000000105e06743 fast_function + 182 47  org.python.python         
    0x0000000105e035a8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12494 48  org.python.python  
    0x0000000105e06743 fast_function + 182 49  org.python.python         
    0x0000000105e035a8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12494 50  org.python.python  
    0x0000000105e003b0 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1638 51  org.python.python    
    0x0000000105dffd44 PyEval_EvalCode + 54 52  org.python.python        
    0x0000000105e1eac7 run_mod + 53 53  org.python.python            
    0x0000000105e1eb6e PyRun_FileExFlags + 137 54  org.python.python     
    0x0000000105e1e6d1 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 698 55 
org.python.python               0x0000000105e2f0e8 Py_Main + 3184 56 
libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff92c937e1 start + 1

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):   rax:
0x000000005137f382  rbx: 0x000000005137f382  rcx: 0x5d65e2b41bbecb33 
rdx: 0x0000000105e9e3a8   rdi: 0x0000000106acd630  rsi:
0x00007fff8de3b0c1  rbp: 0x00007fff59e82c70  rsp: 0x00007fff59e82c40  
r8: 0x00007fff78663788   r9: 0x0000000000000100  r10:
0x0000000000000100  r11: 0x00000001066b3be8   r12: 0x0000000106acd630 
r13: 0x00007fcb524071c0  r14: 0x0000000105e9e3a8  r15:
0x00007fff8de3b0c1   rip: 0x0000000106ac2064  rfl: 0x0000000000010202 
cr2: 0x0000000106ac791c Logical CPU: 1

......................... VM Region Summary: ReadOnly portion of
Libraries: Total=110.2M resident=67.4M(61%)
swapped_out_or_unallocated=42.8M(39%) Writable regions: Total=31.6M
written=12.4M(39%) resident=14.5M(46%) swapped_out=0K(0%)
unallocated=17.1M(54%)   REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      ======= MALLOC                             23.1M MALLOC guard page                    32K STACK GUARD                        56.0M Stack                              8192K VM_ALLOCATE                           4K
__DATA                             4664K
__LINKEDIT                         53.6M
__TEXT                             56.6M
__UNICODE                           544K shared memory                        12K
===========                      ======= TOTAL                             202.5M

Model: iMac12,2, BootROM IM121.0047.B0A, 2 processors, Intel Core 2
Duo, 2.6 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.30f3 Graphics: GeForce GT 610, GeForce GT
610, PCIe, 1024 MB Memory Module: BANK0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 800 MHz,
Kingston, N/A Memory Module: BANK2/DIMM2, 2 GB, DDR3, 800 MHz,
Kingston, N/A Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0 PCI Card:
GeForce GT 610, sppci_displaycontroller, Slot-1 Serial ATA Device: WDC
WD20EARX-00PASB0, 2 TB Serial ATA Device: PIONEER DVD-RW  DVR-216 USB
Device: USB OPTICAL MOUSE, 0x093a  (Pixart Imaging, Inc.), 0x2510,
0x3d200000 / 2
```

Comment: You might get more help on [SU]

Comment: Report crashes to the bug tracker: http://mercurial.selenic.com/bts/